# Python EOF error when reading line

Tags: python, eof

I keep getting an EOF error. I don't see any reason it why should be yelling at me. I've tried running it in 3.3 and in 2.7 so I guess there must be something wrong. And although I don't get any errors when i'm in [Cloud 9](http://c9.io), it won't actually run. And when I use a different IDE, I get that error.

```
Executing the code....
$python3 demo.py
Hello! What is your name?Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 2, in 
    name = input("Hello! What is your name?")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Here's my code.

```
import sys
name = input("Hello! What is your name?")
print("So your name is {0}? Cool!".format(name))
age = input("Now tell me how old you are.")
print("So your name is {0} and you're {1} years old?".format(name, age))
yn = input("Y/N?")
if yn == "y":
    print("Okay good!")
elif yn == "n":
    sys.exit(0)
```

Any help?

Comment: Which program are you running this in?

Comment: @jamylak Looks like something similar to `$ python demo.py < /dev/null` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem is, but maybe consider using raw_input?

According to the docs here (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input):

> Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.

Comment: I think it might have been something wrong with the IDE I was using. I tried running it on IDLE and it ran fine. Sorry about that!

Comment: He's tried it in 3.3 and 2.7 so that's obviously not the solution

Comment: @jamylak Didn't spot that.

Comment: This is true for python 2.x, where `input` is intended to be used for numbers and `raw_input` is intended for text, but in Python 3, only `input` exists, which works for both.

Comment: @Xiam if this was not the solution, it doesn't make any sense to accept it...

Comment: Even though you should use `raw_input` in Python 2, this has nothing to do with getting an EOF error, if you get that with `input` you'd also get it with `raw_input`.

Comment: @MichaelMcClenaghan I already explained that there was no solution. I came to the conclusion on my own that it must have been something wrong with the IDE that I was using. I ran it on IDLE and it went perfectly. I just accepted it because why not.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EOFError

Answer (score -1):

Use `raw_input` Instead of  `input`.

Comment: There is no `raw_input()` in Python 3.

Comment: In python 3, `input()` is the same as `raw_input()`.